# Coefficient cubic for the nested radical equation $\pm \sqrt{n\pm \sqrt{n\pm\sqrt{n\pm \sqrt{n+x}} }}=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals, fixed-point-theorems, nested-radicals

I read a math article on the net that stated:

For the nested radical equation

$$\pm \sqrt{n\pm \sqrt{n\pm\sqrt{n\pm \sqrt{n+x}} }}=x$$

By repeated squaring we get

$$\left( \left( \left( x^2-n \right)^2-n \right)^2-n \right)^2-x-n=0$$

The 16 roots of the polynomial are the solutions for the nested radical equation.

This polynomial can be decomposed into 4 quartics. First one is

$$\left( x^2-n \right)^2-x-n=0$$

The other three quartics had coefficients in the cubic

$$y^3+3y=4(1+ny)$$

The 12 roots are

$$x=-\frac{y-z}{4}\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{(y-2)(y+z)z}{2y}},\quad z=\pm \sqrt{y^2+4}$$

3 choices of y and 4 combinations of $\pm$ sign make 12 solutions.

My question is : how to derive the coefficients of the cubic?

I tried to get the product of the 3 quartics by calculating

$$\frac{\left( \left( \left( x^2-n \right)^2-n \right)^2-n \right)^2-x-n}{\left( x^2-n \right)^2-x-n}=x^{12}-6n\cdot x^{10}+x^9+\mathcal{O}(x^8)$$

Suppose the 3 quaritcs are

$$x^4+a_1x^3+b_1x^2+c_1x+d_1=0 \\
x^4+a_2x^3+b_2x^2+c_2x+d_2=0 \\
x^4+a_3x^3+b_3x^2+c_3x+d_3=0
$$

and $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are 3 roots of the coefficients' cubic.

The product of the 3 quartics give the polynomial

$$x^{12}+(a_1+a_2+a_3)x^{11}+(a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_1a_3+b_1+b_2+b_3)x^{10}+\\
(a_1a_2a_3+a_1b_2+a_1b_3+a_2b_1+a_2b_3+a_3b_1+a_3b_2+c_1+c_2+c_3)x^{9}+\mathcal{O}(x^8)$$

Comparing the coefficients with the original 12th degree polynomial above, apparently $a_1+a_2+a_3=0$.

We need to derive the following equalities to match with the original polynomial.

$$ a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_1a_3=-4n+3 \\
b_1+b_2+b_3=-2n-3 \\
a_1a_2a_3=4 \\
a_1b_2+a_1b_3+a_2b_1+a_2b_3+a_3b_1+a_3b_2=-4n-3 \\
c_1+c_2+c_3=4n $$

How to derive these equalities to obtain the coefficients' cubic?

Answer (score 1):

Applying the infinite iterations, we have:

$$\begin{align}\pm \sqrt{n\pm \sqrt{n\pm\sqrt{n\pm \sqrt{n\color{#c00}{\pm \sqrt{n\pm \sqrt{n\pm\sqrt{n\pm \sqrt{n±\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}
}}}}}=x\end{align}$$

This tells us that, if the original equation has a real root, then it also has a root of the following equation:

$$
\begin{align}&±\sqrt {n+x}=x\\
\implies &n+x=x^2\\
\implies &x^2-x-n=0\end{align}
$$

Now, we will shows that the real roots of the quadratic are equivalent to the original equation. Indeed, using a finite number of iterations and reversing the steps, we have:

$$\begin{align}&±\sqrt {n+x}=x\\
\implies &±\sqrt {n±\sqrt {n+x}}=x\\
\implies &±\sqrt {n±\sqrt {n±\sqrt {n+x}}}=x\\
\implies &±\sqrt{n±\sqrt{n±\sqrt{n± \sqrt{n+x}} }}=x.\end{align}
$$

Therefore, we only need to solve the quadratic:

$$
\begin{align}&x^2-x-n=0\\
\implies &x_{1,2}=\frac {1\color{#c00}{±}\sqrt {1+4n}}{2}\end{align}
$$

If all the signs are $«+»$ in the *iteration*, then the real root equals to:

$$x=\frac {1\color{#c00}{+}\sqrt {1+4n}}{2}$$

If all the signs are $«-»$, in the *iteration*, then the answer is:

$$x=\frac {1\color{#c00}{-}\sqrt {1+4n}}{2}$$

where $n\geqslant-\frac 14$.